# How to pass data from Kafka to Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-python

I am trying to pass data from kafka to spark streaming.

This is what I've done till now:

1. Installed both `kafka` and `spark`
2. Started `zookeeper` with default properties config
3. Started `kafka server` with default properties config
4. Started `kafka producer`
5. Started `kafka consumer`
6. Sent message from producer to consumer. Works fine.
7. Wrote **kafka-spark.py** to receive messages from kafka to spark.
8. I try running `./bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py`
9. I get an error.

**kafka-spark.py -**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark").setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark")
    #sc = SparkContext(appName="KafkaSpark")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    stream=StreamingContext(sc,1)
    map1={'spark-kafka':1}
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(stream, 'localhost:9092', "name", map1) #tried with localhost:2181 too

    print("kafkastream=",kafkaStream)
    sc.stop()
```

**Full Log including the Error on running spark-kafka.py:**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/01/18 13:05:33 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/01/18 13:05:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/18 13:05:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: username
16/01/18 13:05:33 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: username
16/01/18 13:05:33 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(username); users with modify permissions: Set(username)
16/01/18 13:05:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 54446.
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@127.0.0.1:50386]
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 50386.
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-f5490271-cdb7-467d-a915-4f5ccab57f0e
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://127.0.0.1:4040
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll561240765619860252.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO Utils: Copying ~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py to /tmp/spark-18227081-a1c8-43f2-8ca7-cfc4751f023f/userFiles-e93fc252-0ba1-42b7-b4fa-2e46f3a0601e/kafka-spark.py
16/01/18 13:05:34 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py at file:~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py with timestamp 1453118734892
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 58970.
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 58970
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:58970 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 58970)
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager

________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka:1.6.0 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-assembly, Version = 1.6.0.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py", line 33, in <module>
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(stream, 'localhost:9092', "name", map1)
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 80, in createStream
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://127.0.0.1:4040
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-18227081-a1c8-43f2-8ca7-cfc4751f023f
16/01/18 13:05:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-18227081-a1c8-43f2-8ca7-cfc4751f023f/pyspark-fcd47a97-57ef-46c3-bb16-357632580334
```

**EDIT**

On running `./bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar examples/src/main/python/kafka-spark.py` I get the HEXADECIMAL location instead of the actual string:

```
kafkastream= <pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x7fd6c4dad150>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I'm really new to kakfa and spark so I need some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to submit spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_*.jar with your job:

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.jar ./spark-kafka.py
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I already tried that and I get a different error. Check my new edit. I added it.

Comment: Try changing  map1={'spark-kafka':'1'} to  map1={'spark-kafka':1}

Comment: Thanks, now I get `kafkastream= <pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x7fc55106d150>` instead of the actual message. What I want is to print the actual message. `print kafkastream` seems to print something else.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you want to also specify resources to be allocated at the same time:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 20g --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar ./spark-kafka.py
```

If you wanna run your code in a [Jupyter-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/154), then this could be helpful:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar pyspark-shell' #note that the "pyspark-shell" part is very important!!.

    #conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark").setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-Spark")
    #sc = SparkContext(appName="KafkaSpark")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    stream=StreamingContext(sc,1)
    map1={'spark-kafka':1}
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(stream, 'localhost:9092', "name", map1) #tried with localhost:2181 too

    print("kafkastream=",kafkaStream)
    sc.stop()
```

Note the introduction of the following line in `__main__`:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar pyspark-shell'
```

Sources: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/154

Comment: Downloading the jar to `$SPARK_HOME/jars` and adding `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']` like described here solved the problem for me running this in a Jupyter Notebook. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

To print a DStream, spark provides a method pprint for Python. So you'll use

`kafkastream.pprint()`